# Passing arguments to octave function from within bash script

Tags: bash, scripting, command-line, octave

I wrote a function in Octave that takes in a line read from a file (one line at a time) as input argument. I use a bash script to read a line at a time from the file and then pass that as argument to the octave function from within the script.

My bash script looks like so:

```
#!/bin/bash  

while read line
do
  octave --silent --eval 'myOctaveFunc("${line}")'
done < "inFileName"
```

When I execute above script, octave throws errors like:

```
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.2.3/m/miscellaneous/fullfile.m at line 43, column 11
error: evaluating argument list element number 2
error: evaluating argument list element number 1
error:   /usr/libexec/octave/packages/gsl-1.0.8/i386-redhat-linux-gnu-api-v37/PKG_ADD at line 47, column 1
error: addpath: expecting all args to be character strings
error: addpath: expecting all args to be character strings
error: addpath: expecting all args to be character strings
error: addpath: expecting all args to be character strings
```

and so on..

I have been able to run the octave script `myOctaveFunc.m` with input arguments such as `helloWorld` from the command line. The problem arises when I try to run it from within the bash script.

My questions are:
1. How do I get the octave function running from within the bash script?
2. I am using `gvim` to edit the bash script. When I type in the line to invoke the octave script, I see that the `${line}` is colored differently as compared to normal circumstances. Is that because of the `''` used to invoke the octave function? If so, should I be worried about it?

Comment: How do you invoke your octave script outside of the bash script? What do you see when you put "echo octave --silent ..." in the bash script instead of "octave --silent" ?

Comment: @Bruno: The invocation of the octave script (after echo) goes something like: `octave --silent --eval 'myOctaveFunc(helloWorld)'` whereas it should be `octave ... 'myOctaveFunc("helloWorld")'`. I tried `octave ... 'myOctaveFunc(\"helloWorld\")'`. This works fine in bash with an `echo` but fails when invoking the octave script.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The single quotes are preventing the shell from substituting the variable:

```
octave --silent --eval "myOctaveFunc(\"$line\")"
```

If octave lets you use single quotes to quote strings, it will look a little cleaner (inside double quotes, single quotes have no special meaning):

```
octave --silent --eval "myOctaveFunc('$line')"
```

Also, from vim, make sure you save the file in unix format so each line does not end with a carriage return character: `:set ff=unix`

Comment: Also, is the `:set ff=unix` option needed? I am working on a linux machine and do take care to do a `dos2unix` each time I come back from Windows.

Comment: You hadn't told us anything about your environment, so no, not needed.

Comment: It returns me `warning: function 'dbEval' defined within script file '/home/max/octave-dollar/scripts/dbEval.m'` when I run `octave --silent --eval "dbEval(\"hello-world\")"`